# NHibernate and "anonymous" entities

Tags: nhibernate, entity

I have these entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public Child C { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have query which fetches all Parent entities from the database. Then I keep them in memory, and filter them using LINQ queries.

I have noticed that when I do the DB query, NH selects all the Parent entities in one query (and of course fills the Foo property), and for each Parent I access with LINQ, NH fetches the infos of each Child.

How can I do to fetch all infos I need in one unique DB, and use the data with LINQ without it to generate additional DB trips?

Should I use the AliasToBeanResultTransformer? If so, must I create a DTO which will store the infos, like:

```
public class ParentDTO
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

or must I still use the Parent class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eagerly load the children for this query like this (using QueryOver syntax)

```
public IList<Parent> FindAllParentsWithChildren()
{
  ISession s = // Get session
  return s.QueryOver<Parent>()
    .Fetch(p => p.C).Eager
    .List<Parent>();
}
```

An alternative is to change your HBM files to indicate that Child is eagerly loaded by default.  Then you won't need to alter your query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell NHibernate not to use lazy loading for the relationship between the Parent and Child entities.

Comment: How couldn't I think about that :D

Comment: That's actually a bad idea. Using caching, batching and ad-hoc join-fetching is better (see Carl's answer)